# minikube service is failing to expose URL

Tags: minikube

```
F:\Udemy\GitRepo\Kubernetes-Tutorial>kubectl get pod -o wide
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
my-app-deploy-68698d9757-wrs9z   1/1     Running   0          14m   172.17.0.3   minikube   <none>           <none>

F:\Udemy\GitRepo\Kubernetes-Tutorial>minikube service my-app-svc
|-----------|------------|-------------|-----------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |    NAME    | TARGET PORT |             URL             |
|-----------|------------|-------------|-----------------------------|
| default   | my-app-svc |          80 | http://172.30.105.146:30365 |
|-----------|------------|-------------|-----------------------------|
* Opening service default/my-app-svc in default browser...

F:\Udemy\GitRepo\Kubernetes-Tutorial>kubectl describe service my-app-svc
Name:                     my-app-svc
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=my-app
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.98.9.115
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               9001/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30365/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.3:9001
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

F:\Udemy\GitRepo\Kubernetes-Tutorial>kubectl logs my-app-deploy-68698d9757-wrs9z

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.1.RELEASE)

2021-08-21 13:37:21.046  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.d.d.DockerpublishApplication           : Starting DockerpublishApplication v0.0.3 on my-app-deploy-68698d9757-wrs9z with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
2021-08-21 13:37:21.050  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.d.d.DockerpublishApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-08-21 13:37:22.645  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9091 (http)
2021-08-21 13:37:22.659  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-08-21 13:37:22.660  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
2021-08-21 13:37:22.785  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-08-21 13:37:22.785  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1646 ms
2021-08-21 13:37:23.302  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-08-21 13:37:23.496  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9091 (http) with context path ''
2021-08-21 13:37:23.510  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.d.d.DockerpublishApplication           : Started DockerpublishApplication in 3.279 seconds (JVM running for 4.077)

F:\Udemy\GitRepo\Kubernetes-Tutorial>
```

Everything seems to be good, but not working well.

Refused to connect issue comes as below for

> minikube service my-app-svc

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service or application is running on different port as you are getting connection refused.

Spring boot running on the **9091** : `Tomcat started on port(s): 9091 (http) with context path ''`

But your service is redirecting the traffic `TargetPort: 9001/TCP`

Your target port should be **9091** instead of **9001**

Your will access the application over the node port Ip request, which will reach to the K8s service and be forwarded to the `TargetPort: 9091/TCP` on which the application is running.